# jQuery date picker manual trigger

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onclick, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a working version of jQuery date picker, Just need to implement 2 more enhancements to it

[image]

[image]

1. The calendar function is not invoking while clicking the Date Icon,
   however if I click the text field it works well. How to fix this?
2. Clear to today's date button - This presets the date to today's
   date, but I want a click event to happen here because I'm calling an
   other function when a date change happens

   ```
   viewHistoricFund = function () {
       $('#historicDate').datepicker({
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true,
           showButtonPanel: true,
           dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
           monthNames: [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ],
           minDate:"-5y",
           maxDate: 'today',
           onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
               showHistoricDate(selected);
           }
       }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
   },


   $("#clear-historic-date-button").click(function (e) {
       $("#historicDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date()); //Working
       $("#historicDate").trigger("click");  //Not working
       viewHistoricFund();  //Not working
   });
   ```

Could you please help to sort out this issue?

Appreciate your help

Comment: Could anyone help on this please?

Comment: Can you add a more of an example that can be runnable, so others can assist? Use the `<>` icon on the text editor toolbar to create a stacksnippet. (like a fiddle) In the HTML section add the jquery from the left side of the page, and only the elements that would appear in the body.  You'll likely need to add a CDN links for the datepicker needs to the HTML section as well.